# Neo4j Spatial using the MATCH clause

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-spatial

I'm using the neo4j spatial withinDistance function. All the documentation that I've found for this use the START clause.

I'd like to use the newer MATCH clause as [recommended by neo4j](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-start.html). It's also because I want to use the USING INDEX clauses which don't work with START. The question that I have is how do I write the following line with MATCH.

START  h = node:geom('withinDistance:[-41.23,174.79, 20.0]')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geo indexes are implemented as a manual indexes. The only way to query a manual index is the `START` clause. This is the only valid use case for `START` these days. There is no way to query a manual/spatial index using `MATCH`.

N.B. in future versions of Neo4j I expect a way of using `match` for this.

Comment: thanks Stefan. I won't waste anymore time looking for a solution to this.